# Install SQL Server on Windows Runner via GitHub Actions

Tags: c#, .net, github, github-actions, chocolatey

I need to install SQL Server Developer edition on my **windows-latest** environment in GitHub Actions.
I use Chocolatey utility for this. Today, it worked several times and everything was OK, but later it began to drop any connections to install any packages of SQL Server. Maybe it's because of huge size 1,3GB? How to explain that? What other things I can do to install the SQL Server? I need it for E2E tests as they can't run without installed MS-SQL instance.

Comment: If the error is really caused by rate limiting, you can try to cache the installer files or the the installation with https://github.com/actions/cache

Comment: Will it cache globally between invocations of the same workflow or the cache is used to cache data while workflow is running only?

Comment: Yes, it's designed to cache between different runs of workflows. More details can be found here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows